# An undefined notation $P(\{x\in \mathcal{X}:g(x)\in A\})\stackrel{?}{=} P(\{x\in S:g(X(x))\in A\})$ in Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm reading Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference*. In the beginning of Chapter 2, they said that:

> Formally, if we write $y=g(x)$, the function $g(x)$ defines a mapping from the original $\color{red}{\text{sample space}}$ of $X$, $\mathcal{X}$, to a new sample space, $\mathcal{Y}$, the sample space of the random variable $Y$. That is,
> $$g(x):\mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Y}.$$

On the next page, they said that:

> $$
> \begin{array}{lll}
> P(Y\in A)
> &=& P(g(X)\in A) \\
> &=& P(\{x\in \mathcal{X}: g(x)\in A\}) \\
> &=& P(X\in g^{-1}(A))\tag{*}
> \end{array}$$

My question is about the notation $P(\{x\in \mathcal{X}: g(x)\in A\})$.
**I want to check my following guesses:**

1. The notation $\mathcal{X}$ should be the $\color{red}{\text{image}}$ of the random variable $X$, not the $\color{red}{\text{sample space}}$ of the random variable $X$. Am I right?

I don't think it was a typo since the authors mentioned that again on page 50:

> When transformations are made, it is important to keep track of the sample spaces of the random variables; otherwise, much confusion can arise. When the transformation is from $X$ to $Y=g(X)$, it is most convenient to use
> $$\mathcal{X}=\{x:f_X(x)>0\}\text{ and }\mathcal{Y}=\{y:y=g(x)\text{ for some }x\in \mathcal{X}\}.$$

2. $P(\{x\in \mathcal{X}: g(x)\in A\})$ should be defined as $\sum\limits_{g(x)\in A}P(X=x)$ or $\int_{g(x)\in A}P(X=x)$.
3. Suppose that the random variable $X$ is from $S$ to $\mathcal{X}$. In rigorous, (*) should be written as
   $$
   \begin{array}{lll}
   P(Y\in A)
   &=& P(g(X)\in A) \\
   &=& P(\{x\in \color{red}{S}: g(\color{red}{X}(x))\in A\}) \\
   &=& P(X\in g^{-1}(A))
   \end{array}$$

Comment: 1) if $g:\mathcal X\to \mathcal Y$, then $\mathcal X$ is the sample space. The image is $g(\mathcal X)\subset \mathcal Y$. 2) very strange. Is there a typo ? If $X: S\to \mathcal X$, then $$\mathbb P\{g(X)\in A\}=\int_{\mathcal X}g(x)\mu_X(\mathrm d x)=\int_{\mathcal X}g(x)\mathbb P\{X\in \mathrm d x\}.$$ 3) Correct.

Comment: There are two equivalent point of views. Either you suppose that there is some measurable sample space $S$ endowed with a probability measure $P$, and you observe $X$, which is a function from $S$ to $\mathcal{X}$ (and then it should be as you write). But, if you are only interested in the law of $X$, you can completely forget about the space $S$ and only consider the pushforward of $P$ by $X$ (that, with an abuse of notation, we will still denote by $P$). With this new point of view, $P$ is a measure on $\mathcal{X}$,and $P(g(X)\in A)$ is a notation for $P(\{x\in \mathcal{X}, g(x)\in A\})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed this question with the author.
It is indeed
$$P_X(\{x\in \mathcal{X}:g(x)\in A\})=P(\{s\in S:g(X(s))\in A\}),$$ where $X$ is a random variable from $S$ to $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
Thanks for all comments.